# How many pairs of numbers between 0 and n-1 are equal to z mod n?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

I want to know how to compute this function:

$f : \mathbb{Z}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

$f(z) = |\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{Z}_m^2 \mid xy \equiv z  \}|$

Comment: What is the sum over in the last line?

Comment: Crap @IgorRivin I have to change that, its for a more general question but I wrote it in that form here...

Comment: If you're curious, the function I really want is $f(m) = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{Z}_m^k \times \mathbb{Z}_m^k \mid \langle x, y \rangle = 0 \}$, and this other function in the question ends up being in the recurrence as the base case.

Comment: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, it suffices to compute this function when $m$ is a prime power, in which case the task is easy.

Comment: I think I have a nicer solution actually: $f (z) = n(n - \phi (n))$

Comment: Your last formula is definitely wrong. For example, when $m=p$ is a prime, we have $f(1)=p-1$ and $f(0)=2p-1$.

Comment: If $z$ is coprime to $m$, you have $f(z) = \varphi(m)$.  If not, it's more complicated.

Comment: Thanks @GHfromMO I realized that when I was writing it up... I now do not think it's not going to yield anything friendly for my recurrence, but am still curious

Comment: Well, I told you what to do. Find out the (easy) answer when $m$ is a prime power, and then apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: So for squarefree $n$, we should have $f(z) = \prod_{i} p_i^{\phi(p_i)}$, $p_i$ being a prime factor of $n$?

Comment: No. For $m$ prime, $f(z)=p-1$ when $z$ is coprime with $p$, and $f(z)=2p-1$ when $z$ is divisible by $p$. For $m$ a power of $p$ the answer is similar but slightly more complicated: $f(z)$ depends on the exponent of $p$ in $z$.

Comment: Where $m = p$ in the first case?

Comment: Yes. I meant, for $m=p$ prime, $f(z)=p-1$ when $z$ is coprime with $p$ etc.

Comment: I can't quite figure out the prime power case either.. any hints there?

Comment: Well, this is not of research level, but here is a hint. Put $m=p^2$, and then calculate $f(0)$, then $f(p)$, then $f(1)$. These are the three different values $f(z)$ in this case. If this is still too hard for you, then do this for $p=2$, then $p=3$, and so on. This is one way we do mathematics: we specialize a problem and then make it progressively harder. At any rate, your question would be more suitable at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this is by far not research level, I cannot keep myself from posting a very simple solution which somehow has not been mentioned in the comments above.

I use the basic fact that the congruence $ax\equiv b\pmod m$ has exactly $(a,m)$ solutions if $(a,m)\mid(b,m)$, and does not have any solutions otherwise. As a result,
  $$ f(z) = \sum_{y\in{\mathbb Z_m}\colon (y,m)\mid(z,m)} (y,m) = \sum_{d\mid(z,m)} d\varphi(m/d) $$
(the number of those $y\in\mathbb Z_m$ with $(y,m)=d$ is $\varphi(m/d)$). This can be further re-written, for instance, as
  $$ f(z) = m \sum_{d\mid(z,m)} \prod_{p\mid m/d} \Big(1-\frac1p\Big). $$

Comment: Nice and useful indeed.

Comment: Thanks so much! Misplaced the question on here, didn't read the rules

Comment: Confused about the notation in the product at the end, could you or someone else perhaps clarify @Seva? 

Edit: figured it out, was associating the divides symbol before the division sign but it makes sense now.